# context.setLineDash([20, 20]) not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My code is not drawing dashed line. It simply draws the full line and misses the dashed line and I can't think of any reason why it is not working.

```js
class Road {
  constructor(x, width, laneCount = 3) {
    this.x = x;
    this.width = width;
    this.laneCount = laneCount;

    this.left = x - width / 2;
    this.right = x + width / 2;
    const infinity = 1000000000;
    this.top = -infinity;
    this.bottom = infinity;
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

    for (let i = 0; i <= this.laneCount; i++) {
      const x = lerp(this.left, this.right, i / this.laneCount);

      ctx.beginPath();
      if (i > 0 && i < this.laneCount) {
        ctx.setLineDash([20, 20]);
      } else {
        ctx.setLineDash([]);
      }
      ctx.moveTo(x, this.top);
      ctx.lineTo(x, this.bottom);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't set different properties for different parts of the same path (draw properties only "kick in" once `ctx.stroke()` and/or `ctx.fill()` are called, so you can issue a million .setLineDash but only the last one before stroke/fill is the one that gets used). If you need different styles, you need to draw multiple paths. Also note that `Inifnity` _already exists_, it's a basic JS primitive that does exactly what you think it does in arithmetic context. Don't declare a variable that isn't even a particularly large value and then call it "infinity" =)

Comment: Thanks a lot your infinity advised worked for me. Otherwise I have been wondering rest of my life that why it didn't worked. :)